# Why must this ratio of these likelihood functions be less than $1$?

Tags: proof-explanation, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample from a binomial $\text{bin}(k,p)$ population where $p$ is known and $k$ is unknown.  We attempt to maximize $L(k | x,p)$ the likelihood function without differentiation.

If $k \lt \text{max}_i x_i$ then $L(k | x, p) = 0$, so the MLE is an integer $k \ge \text{max}_i x_i$ that satisfies $L(k|x,p) / L(k-1 | x, p) \ge 1$ and $L(k+1 | x, p) / L(k | x,p) \lt 1$.

Why does $k$ have to satisfy these two inequalities?  And how can it satisfy the second inequality if it satisfies the first?

Since $L(k | x,p) = \prod_{i=1}^n $  $k\choose x_i$ $p^{x_i}(1-p)^{k-x_i}$, if the first inequality is true then the second inequality should be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find the maximum of $L(k\mid x,p)$ for any $k$ then you should be finding a $k$ such that $L(k \mid x,p) \geq L(m \mid x,p)$ for any $m.$

In particular, setting $m = k - 1,$ you would have
$$ L(k \mid x,p) \geq L(k - 1 \mid x,p) \tag1 $$
and setting $m = k + 1$ you would have
$$ L(k \mid x,p) \geq L(k + 1 \mid x,p). \tag2$$
But $(1)$ gives you
$$ \frac{ L(k \mid x,p)}{L(k - 1 \mid x,p)} \geq 1, $$
which is one of the inequalities you're supposed to have,
and $(2)$ gives you
$$ \frac{ L(k + 1\mid x,p)}{L(k  \mid x,p)} \leq 1 , $$
which is almost the other inequality; the only change is that you were
supposed to have  $<$ instead of $\leq.$
But unless the values of $L(m \mid x,p)$ for $m > k$ are all equal to each other
then at some point you will have $<$ instead of $\leq,$
so choose your $k$ to be on the left side of the first $<$ inequality.